# Where I can see SO moderator election details via new SE android app?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow, android-app, election

I'm unable access Stackoverflow moderator election details on [StackExchange Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin)!  Can anybody suggest how to access that?

If it's not possible, what is the use of the native app? I can get update or view what's happening on 2014 SO election! Why is there such a limitation? They can easily advertise with another option in Navigation-drawer! or any alert like *'16hrs left for voting!'*

What is the reason? Is the SO election API not yet ready? or are they intentionally not implementing that option for some reasons?

**When I recognized this problem?**

I'm on long vacation, I missed this election alert because of using this app! I stopped using SO on browsers when this app released! so I missed this alerts! I'm expected at-least one push notification, click on that should open SO moderator election page in Browser ! such that it will increase vote rate of elections!

**Really we need this in Future:**

[image]

Comment: Good idea, I like it! But maybe since the Android app is still in early stage, this feature is not that important.

Comment: @AndrewT. I agree with you ! but they should mention it like _Stack Exchange Beta_ in Google play! May be I'm talking to much in perfectionist's way !

Answer (score 2):

An election is a site event which shows up in the "Community Bulletin" on the websites. In the mobile apps, this shows up in your feed the day the event is created. Currently my feed shows the newest community bulletin item on Stack Overflow, the blog post for the new podcast episode. Before this, it shows an item for the elections which when you tapped opened up the elections webpage in a browser.

It's not likely for the app to special case elections to be in any more places than in simply bringing the community bulletin into the feed, as it already does.

Comment: Thanks for the info! But I feel many of them forgot to vote, who use this app! (I'm on long vacation, I missed this election alert because of using this app!)